# Limit number of concurrent sessions per user using IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4

We have a couple of users which we might are sharing their user account with other users. We are thinking on adding functionality within IdentityServer4 which limits the number of concurrent sessions a user can have to prevent this behaviour.

This won't prevent the users from sharing user accounts from time to time during the day, but we will at least be able to stop concurrent use of our systems.

We are thinking on counting the number of refresh tokens used by each user account and if they exceeds a certain limit, the oldest refresh tokens and access tokens are deleted for that user, this until the amount of refresh tokens is equal the allowed limit.

Any input on how this functionality can be implemented using IdentityServer4? We would also like to inform the user why the reference token was deleted therefore causing an log-off.

Answer (score 0):

Logically when a user exceeds its limit of concurrent sessions, it still should have the ability to be authenticated, so I would vote against considering identityserver as the right place for such functionality.

What are you planning to return to the user when limit is reached? you are not authorized to access this resource? this does not sound right.

I recommend applying such feature in the resource itself, count the current sessions using your application logic, then redirect the user to a page telling that limit is exceeded.

**UPDATE:**

Check this Github discussion where IdentityServer contributes responded to a relatively similar query.
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/736

Comment: The nice thing with doing this within IdSrv4 is that it’s centralized. We have OIDC clients which we can’t easily implement this session limit logic.